# Streaming/Sending audio files with UNet

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I have a small app where one user can talk to the other. It's pretty much a walkie-talkie but one sided(Meaning only one can speak and the other can hear). I have integrated UNet with this app(I need to do it over the LAN and also I have other info to send through the network).

With the other messages(they are simple strings) everything works great, but when I try to send an `AudioClip` it will be null on the other side. I guess this happens because the `AudioClip` is not serializable or something similar. So I found `SyncListFloat` and I add all the audio data to this one(this kinda takes a lot of time which is sort of problematic, I think this happens because the message sending after each Add) but then the Player Prefab(which I use to send data) is no longer added to the scene. If I remove the `SyncListFloat` variable from the Player script everything works great(except for the audio sending part, obviously).

I would like to know how can I send and audio files through UNet and if `SyncListFloat` is the answer how can I add the whole byte array in one go.